# The first-order metatheory of HoTT

Tags: logic, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Does there exist a (say, simply typed) first-order theory which axiomatizes a universe of $\infty$-groupoids, in a similar manner to how ZFC can be considered as an axiomatization of the universe of sets (or perhaps as an axiomatization of what *a* universe of sets should look like)? The connection with the title of this question is that it seems to like this should be roughly equivalent to having a first-order metatheory of something like HoTT whose objects are to be interpeted as the types and terms of HoTT, with the native equality symbol "$=$" of the metatheory read as the judgemental equality "$\equiv$" of the type theory. (Note that it is irrelevant here that the dependent types of HoTT mimic the logical symbols $\exists,\forall$, just as the need for the logical symbols $\wedge,\vee$ in ZFC is not obviated by the fact that the set-theoretic operations $\cap,\cup$ behave similarly.)

It seems to me that HoTT does not really describe the model in simplicial sets in an entirely analogous way to how ZFC describes the set-theoretic universe. Rather (and please correct me insofar as I am mistaken!), it provides a language for doing constructions with simplicial sets (or the analogous objects in other $(\infty,1)$-toposes or something). (For comparison, ZFC allows us to formalize computations regarding concrete sets, but it also allows us to quantify over sets and therefore to reason about many distinct concrete computations simultaneously, all internally to the theory.) To illustrate the difference here, consider the deduction rule
$$
\frac{``\Gamma\vdash A:\mathcal{U}", \quad ``\Gamma,x:A\vdash B:\mathcal{U}",\quad ``\Gamma,x:A\vdash b\equiv b':B"}{``\Gamma\vdash \lambda x.b \equiv \lambda x.b' : \prod_{x:A} B"}
$$
of HoTT, which is $\Pi$-Intro-Eq in Appendix A of the HoTT book, except I've added quotation marks to emphasize that we are working with strings "internal" to the HoTT formal system. In other words, if we have already asserted strings of the form on the top line, then the programming language allows us to assert the string on the bottom line. Thus, the metatheory should have an axiom of theorem which looks something (very, very roughly) like
$$
``(\forall A,B(x:A))(\forall b,b':B)( b= b' \Rightarrow \lambda x.b = \lambda x.b')"
$$
which states in the formal language of the metatheory what the deduction rule does. (And this looks like it should follow for the axioms of equality in FOL.) Moreover, the metatheory should have some sort of axiom expressing the fact that the only types that are judgementally equal are those that can be shown to be judgementally equal via the deduction rules in Appendix A of HOTT. That is to say, ZFC has many axioms telling us that things are not equal --- e.g. the axiom defining the empty set in ZFC implies that $\varnothing \neq \{\varnothing\}$. But it seems to me (and once again, please correct me if I am mistaken) that the statement ${\mathbf{1}}\not\equiv{\mathbf{0}}$ regarding the empty and unit types is a statement *in the metatheory, about HoTT,* rather than a statement in HoTT itself. But $``\neg({\mathbf{1}}={\mathbf{0}})"$ should be a theorem (maybe a nontrivial one) of the metatheory.

Comment: I don’t think this is actually an answer to your question in any way, but it sounds like you might be interested in the idea of “Two Level Type Theory”

Answer (score 5):

I don't really understand how the question in your first sentence is related to the rest of what you wrote.  I have a guess, but let me pontificate a bit first about how I think the comparison between ZFC and dependent type theory is usually understood.  If my answer isn't what you had in mind, maybe you can clarify what led you to ask about first-order theories of $\infty$-groupoids.

(FWIW, in my opinion, unqualified "HoTT", i.e. "homotopy type theory", refers to the entire subject area, not to a specific formal theory.  The specific formal theory of [the book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) is sometimes called "Book HoTT".)

##### Deductive systems

The basic object in foundations of mathematics is a [deductive system](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/deductive+system): a collection of rules for deriving judgments.  Note that a deductive system does not include any way to "reject" a judgment: all we can do with a judgment is derive or deduce it.

Dependent type theory is itself a deductive system.  Its judgments are of the form $\Gamma\vdash a:A$ and $\Gamma \vdash a\equiv b:A$, where $\Gamma$ is a context of variables assigned to types, and its rules are the sort presented in the appendix of the HoTT Book.  Sometimes one takes "$\Gamma \vdash A$ is a type" and "$\Gamma\vdash A\equiv B$ as types" as basic judgments too, although in a Russell universe system those could be identified with $A:\mathscr{U}$ and $A\equiv B :\mathscr{U}$ for some universe $\mathscr{U}$.

In the case of ZFC, things are potentially more confusing because there are two levels, the logic and the "theory".  The deductive system here is single-sorted first-order logic.  Its judgments (in a natural-deduction presentation) are of the form $\Delta \mid \Gamma \vdash \phi$, where $\Delta$ is a list of variables, and $\phi$ is a logical formula and $\Gamma$ is a list of formulas containing only the free variables in $\Delta$.  Its rules are things like the introduction and elimination rules for each connective and quantifier.  Inside this deductive system, with basic relation symbol $\in$, we then assert the axioms of ZFC.

So, at a formal level, there is no need for a first-order metatheory of type theory the same way ZFC sits inside first-order logic: type theory is its own deductive system.

##### Semantics

A "model" or "interpretation" of a deductive system consists, informally, of an assignation of "things" to its judgments in such a way that its rules are valid.

The usual way to describe a model of dependent type theory is to specify a category of some kind and say that the judgments are to be interpreted using objects and morphisms in that category.  (To be precise, it should be some kind of [categorical model of dependent types](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/categorical+model+of+dependent+types).)  For instance, Book HoTT has a model in the category of simplicial sets in this sense.

A correspondingly general semantics of first-order logic involves a [hyperdoctrine](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hyperdoctrine).  Very often this is the hyperdoctrine of subobjects in some category, and classically one generally restricts only to case when that category is $\rm Set$.  In the single-sorted case, we specify a single object of that category to be the type of "things", with morphisms or relations on that object corresponding to the symbols, and such that the axioms hold.  Working in $\rm Set$, we thus get the standard notion of "model of ZFC": a set $V$ together with a relation $[\in] \subseteq V\times V$ such that the axioms of ZFC hold.

There is indeed a difference here: a category such as simplicial sets in which we model Book HoTT doesn't have to "sit inside" anything else; while at least with categorical semantics phrased in this way, a model of ZFC does have to sit inside some ambient category.  However, the "quantifications over sets" of ZFC are still semantically the same sort of thing as the quantifications ($\Pi$-types) of type theory: operations on (sub)objects in some category.  A $\Pi$-type over a universe $\mathscr{U}$ in type theory seems to me like "reasoning about many distinct concrete things" simultaneously in the same way that a quantifier $\forall$ over sets in ZFC.

Note also that just as a deductive system doesn't have any way to "reject" a judgment, a model of that system doesn't have to respect non-derivability.  A certain definitional equality may not be derivable in type theory, but the analogous equality might still hold in some model.  Similarly, a certain formula may not be provable in ZFC, but it might still hold in some model.

##### Disequality

Disequality is confusing because first-order logic doesn't have an equality *judgment*.  The disequality $\varnothing \neq \{\varnothing\}$ is a *formula* such that the judgment $\vdash \varnothing \neq \{\varnothing\}$ can be derived.  Accordingly, in any model, the interpretation of this statement must be "true".  Note, though, that in the generality of categorical semantics, this doesn't mean that the semantical objects interpreting $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$ are distinct: in the trivial model in the terminal category, all formulas are true, including both $\varnothing \neq \{\varnothing\}$ and $\varnothing = \{\varnothing\}$.

Analogously, dependent type theory contains a type $\neg {\rm Id}_{\mathscr{U}}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{1})$, and a term $t$ such that the judgment $\vdash t : \neg {\rm Id}_{\mathscr{U}}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{1})$ is derivable.

Type theory *also* contains a judgment $\mathbf{0} \equiv \mathbf{1} : \mathscr{U}$, which is *not derivable*.  This is a truly meta-theoretic statement *about* the deductive system, not anything inside the theory.  Importantly, therefore, it may not be respected by models; this particular example is confusing because of the positive derivability of $\vdash t : \neg {\rm Id}_{\mathscr{U}}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{1})$.  But there are other pairs of types, like $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$, for which $\mathbb{N}\equiv\mathbb{Z} : \mathscr{U}$ is not derivable, but such that there are nontrivial models in which the interpretations of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are equal (for the strict sort of semantic equality that corresponds to syntactic judgmental equality).

The analogue of this in ZFC would be a statement that a certain formula $\phi$ is not provable.  Again, this is a metatheoretic statement that may not be respected in models.  Of course, if $\neg \phi$ *is* provable, then $\phi$ can't hold in a nontrivial model.  But if $\phi$ is an undecidable statement like the continuum hypothesis, then it is unprovable and neverthless there are nontrivial models in which it holds.

In particular, we never assert an *axiom* that "the only types that are judgementally equal are those that can be shown to be judgementally equal via the deduction rules".  Syntactically, this statement is just true by definition: what it *means* for two syntactic types to be judgmentally equal is that they can be shown to be so by the deduction rules.  And semantically, this statement is generally false: any given model will validate (the interpretations of) more judgmental equalities than are derivable syntactically.  Analogously, in first-order logic we never assert that "the only formulas that are provable are those that can be shown to be provable via the rules of logic" --- this is either a definition of "provable" or a false statement for any particular model.

##### Conclusion

I hope I've explained clearly how the differences between ZFC/FOL and dependent type theory manifest from viewing them both as deductive systems.  The differences come from differences in the presentations, such as the presence or absence of an equality judgment, the presence or absence of multiple types/sorts, and so on.

Given that, I don't entirely understand how a "first-order metatheory of Book HoTT" would be related to a first-order axiomatization of $\infty$-groupoids.  By a "metatheory of Book HoTT" I would understand a description of the syntax of Book HoTT, sufficient to prove statements like "$\mathbb{N} \equiv \mathbb{Z} : \mathscr{U}$ is not derivable", and to state and prove the interpretability of that syntax in appropriate categories.  Such a metatheory certainly exists: lots of people study metatheory of type theories.

By contrast, by a "first-order axiomatization of $\infty$-groupoids", I would understand a theory in first-order logic, like ZFC, whose models are "universes of $\infty$-groupoids" in the same way that the models of ZFC are "universes of sets".  My best guess at the connection you have in mind would be a first-order theory whose models are the *models* of Book HoTT, regarded as small categories inside $\rm Set$ the same way a model of ZFC is a single object of $\rm Set$ with a relation on it.  In other words, the first-order theory of a [category with families](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/categorical+model+of+dependent+types), or some variant thereof, with all the additional type structure corresponding to Book HoTT.  Is this the sort of thing you have in mind?

**Edit:** Based on the comments, let me add a bit more about how this latter thing is and isn't what you might have in mind.  On the one hand, this is a way to specify, if you insist on working in an ambient first-order logic, a structure that corresponds roughly to a dependent type theory such as Book HoTT.

However, because of the differences I explained above, formulating such a theory inside FOL and then working in it would not really be analogous to formulating ZFC inside FOL and then working in it.  It would be more like formulating the notion of "model of ZFC" inside FOL.  Normally when we work in ZFC, the notion of "proposition" we use is the one from the ambient FOL, with no other choice; but if instead we formulated "model of ZFC" in FOL then there would be two different notions of "proposition", the ambient one and the one pertaining to the model.  The one you would want to use is the one pertaining to the model, so in essence you wouldn't really be using the ambient FOL you started from, and it would be a tedious translation to add an extra layer of indirection to everything

Similarly, if you formulate the first-order theory of a CWF, you'll end up with two notions of "proposition": the ambient one of the FOL, and the internally defined propositions-as-types notion of the DTT of the CWF.  The latter is the one you want to use, so you wouldn't actually be using the ambient FOL much, and you'd again have the tedious layer of indirection.  If you want to work with Book HoTT, it's much better to implement it directly as a deductive system than try to talk about its models inside FOL.

A different question is whether there is a "first-order theory of $\infty$-groupoids" that could be formulated inside FOL without indirection, analogously to ZFC.  I don't think anyone has succeeded in writing down such a thing, and I'm dubious that it is possible, because the identification of propositions with certain types seems crucial to the way HoTT works, whereas breaking off the propositions into a separate level of FOL seems like it would prevent that.  But I don't have a watertight argument against it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I do want to know the answer regarding "a first-order theory whose models are the models of Book HoTT...," but I didn't frame the original question in this way because it isn't really clear to me how degenerate or nondegenerate a "model of Book HoTT" is.  So, I wanted to leave open the possibility of needing to add some additional axioms postulating that the model is "sufficiently initial" in the relevant category of models of the basic theory. (Continued below.)

Comment: My imagined connection with a  "metatheory of Book HoTT" was that such a metatheory should be a first order axiomatization of "a category with families, or some variant thereof, with all the additional type structure corresponding to Book HoTT" that is sufficiently initial. As for your question regarding "what led [me] to ask about first-order theories of ∞-groupoids," the honest (and probably less than satisfying) answer is that as someone who learned FOL and set theory before being exposed to category theory, who was exposed to Metamath before CIC, this seemed a natural thing to want!

Comment: In part, I was trying to flesh out the following thesis (that I do not ascribe to): "mathematical objects should be located in the universe of $\infty$-groupoids rather than the universe of sets." I am not claiming that anyone actually ascribes to this view! But I wanted to try and understand it regardless. I think you can ascribe to this thesis while still believing the "two levels" aspect of ZFC is worth maintaining.

Comment: In other words, if we were to rewrite the metamath database set.mm *after* the part developing FOL with \infty-groupoids in mind, what would the resultant theory look like?

Comment: I think you are using "metatheory" in a rather more specific way than I am used to.  Usually the "metatheory" of a formal system is an umbrella term including all sorts of proofs about its syntax, such as canonicity, normalization, decidability of typechecking, admissibility of certain rules, as well as proofs connecting its syntax to semantics, such as a definition of certain semantic structures and construction of interpretations into those structures.  You seem to be using "metatheory" to refer only to a description of the semantic structures into which a theory interprets.

Comment: Regarding models of Book HoTT, note that *a* model of a theory need not be the initial model.  Moreover, initiality is not a first-order property.

Comment: I've added some more detail to the answer about how the first-order theory of a model of Book HoTT is and isn't what you want.

Comment: I think one terminological subtlety here is whether we refer to a FO theory as an axiomatization of the objects that appear in the theory or of the totality of the structure thereof. In the FO theory of groups, the objects are not groups but group ur-elements. In ZFC, the objects are sets. Thus, if the FO theory of groups axiomatizes the notion of a group, ZFC axiomatizes the notion of a universe of sets. We don't need to add an extra level. Similarly, an axiomatization of the universe of $\infty$-groupoids should be a FO theory which quantifies over different $\infty$-groupoids.

Comment: In an FOL axiomatization of some sort of mathematical structure, you typically cannot talk about the whole structure internally. So indeed, if you wanted to be able to talk about universes of sets internally this would require an extension of theory, like NBG. But ZFC axiomatizes the notion of a universe of sets without allowing you to internally work with the whole universe.

Comment: Terminological nitpicking aside, this is just to say that the final paragraph of your edit addresses my original question. However, I find it very surprising! I think most people think that FOL is, at least in principle, sufficient to model all mathematical practice. So, if it is true that the universe of \infty-groupoids (or types or whatever) *cannot* be modeled in this way, it runs counter to expectation!

Comment: I do think however that an axiomatization of "the universe of $\infty$-groupoids" would have two levels of logic, the ambient one and the internal one. But I don't think this is that different from how in ZFC we have two levels of *propositional* logic, the ambient one and the one furnished by $\cap,\cup$ and whatnot.

Comment: Yes, that distinction is similar to the point I was making in the (new) antepenultimate paragraph.  And yes, it takes some effort when learning type theory to wean oneself of the addition to first-order logic.  But once you get used to it, you may find that type theory is a better match for mathematical practice than anything encoded in FOL.  For instance, often in practice we prove a theorem that two objects are isomorphic, and then later on apply that isomorphism to transfer statements back and forth. (cont.)

Comment: ... But in FOL, a theorem that $A\cong B$ is an $\exists$ statement that doesn't carry any information about the specific isomorphism that was constructed in the proof.  One can play games to get around this, of course (at least for set-level mathematics), but I find the type-theoretic representation more natural, where the theorem can be simply a construction of an element of the type of isomorphisms.

Comment: Finally, it's true that in ZFC we maintain two levels of logic that nevertheless end up being isomorphic.  However, the reason they're isomorphic is that the axioms of ZFC make explicit reference to the ambient FOL, e.g. the axiom of separation, which the rules of type theory don't do.  But it's possible there may be some way to make it work anyway.

Comment: The rules of type theory are syntactic, though. That is to say, in ZFC we define unions and intersections because $\cap$ and $\cup$ are not primitive syntactic objects, but in type theory dependent type formers are built into the syntax, right? Is there an obstruction to treating intersections and unions in set theory in a similar way?

Comment: ZFC is usually formulated with the separation axiom as merely "there exists a set such that ...", but I think you can also formulate it with a set-forming syntactic *operator*.  In that case, $\cap$ and $\cup$ would be instances of that.

Comment: If you think it should be possible to formulate a first-order theory of $\infty$-groupoids, don't let me discourage you: give it a try!  If you succeed, fantastic!  If not, you may understand more about why I'm doubtful.